# Can I prevent users from creating workspaces in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm in charge of creating a TFS instance that will be used for, among other things, source control. The source control directory structure needs to mirror another directory, and as such I need to be able to allow users to add, remove, and edit files anywhere within the source control space, but not be able to create new folders, or alter the directory structure in any way (I've already solved the problem of synching source control to the other directory).

My question is, is it possible to map my TFS project to a public workspace, lockdown permissions to that workspace so that users can only use it to manage files, and not the directory structure, and also configure it so that users cannot create a local workspace (or, at the least, cannot publish/shelve) changes from that local workspace?

Comment: Would it be enough to simply prevent adding files and folders in the root?

Comment: Root of source control or root of the workspace? If source control, that would be fine, but I'm not sure how to do that either. If the workspace, I would assume that that wouldn't work unless I can lock users out from creating/using any other workspace.

Comment: And I realize now that I misinterpreted your question. No, at the root is actually not enough. I need to keep them from being able to change the directory structure at any/every level.